# Delete file with powershell first 2 characters of the file name are the same

Tags: powershell

I am new with Powershell. I have created a few scripts to delete all files in certain log directories. Now I need to create a script to delete some .log files but not all from a certain directory.  All of the files start with 20,  "20*.log or 20*.bat. Can I do this with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -File -Filter "20*" | Where-Object {(($_.Extension -match ".log") -or ($_.Extension -match ".bat"))}
```